# functions into live({ and into ajax({ beforeSend: gets all fired after success:

Tags: jquery

I have this simple code, where on live(click:) an external link is called through ajax(). What seems wrong is that two functions where fired only on ajax({success:}).

here the code:

```
$('.ajaxLink').live({
    click :  function(e) {

        $this = $(this);
        var myLink = $this.attr('href');
        var myId = $this.attr('id');

        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({  // this is fired only AFTER content load
            scrollTop : 0
        }, 1500);

        $.ajax({ type: 'GET',   
             url: myLink,   
             async: false,
             dataType: 'html',

             beforeSend : function() {
                caricaModal.open();  // this is also fired only after content load
             },                      // is just an animation on a div.

             success : function(page) {
                caricaModal.close(); // this is fired at good timing

            // some more code here where I insert (page) in the DOM

            }
        });

    }

});
```

If you wonder how much time this takes to load the page it takes about 1.5 seconds, and yes, the fact is that when I click nothing happens before things have loaded and inserted into DOM.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your synchronous ajax call locks up the browser, thereby pausing the animation thread created by `.animate`. When you call `.animate`, the browser does not wait for it to finish before evaluating the next ($.ajax) statement, so the sajax call effectively pauses it until the server has responded. Try putting the ajax call into `.animate`'s callback, or removing the `async: false` option.

Comment: does this means that async: and beforeSend: can't live together?

Comment: Hmmm. That's what it looks like, but you can't be sure unless you can prove it. It does seem to make sense though.